# NodeJS MySQL apostrophe reduplication with INSERT query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm doing my project Nodejs and MySQL and I have some problem with query with apostrophe. I got all of the data from github api and it normally works fine. but If data have single apostrophe('), it will get Syntax Error.

And the Error is like this.

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's computer engineering classes.', '2017-08-28T04:05:02Z', '2018-10-21T12:04:50Z'' at line 1
```

At first, I was thinking about using regular expressions to get rid of all ' but this is not a good way to correct the original data itself.

I search the solutions in google but it's really hard to find with this problem. Is there any google idea or solutions?

```
  // // User Repository Information API Process
  request(repositoryOptions, function (error, response, data) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    let result = JSON.parse(data);

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      // console.log(result[i]);

      let sid = shortid.generate();
      let githubid = result[i].owner.login;
      let name = result[i].name;
      let githuburl = result[i].html_url;
      let explanation = result[i].description;
      let created_at = result[i].created_at;
      let updated_at = result[i].updated_at;


      let sqlData = `('${sid}', '${githubid}', '${name}', '${githuburl}', '${explanation}', '${created_at}', '${updated_at}')`;
      console.log(sqlData);

      let sql = `INSERT INTO Personal_Data (id, githubid, name, githuburl, explanation, pjdate1, pjdate2) VALUES ${sqlData}`;
      db.query(sql);
    }
  })
```

Comment: check your sqlData values and their converted values. after all, you have to use mysql.format method to prevent sql injection. so check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself. @scetiner helps me about the keyword.

I create array and put it all variables. and because of the SQL Injection attack, I have to add placeholders(I'm not sure what is called. it's look like ?,?,?,?,?)

Anyway Here's my code that I modified.

```
request(repositoryOptions, function (error, response, data) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    let result = JSON.parse(data);

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      // console.log(result[i]);

      let sid = shortid.generate();
      let githubid = result[i].owner.login;
      let name = result[i].name;
      let githuburl = result[i].html_url;
      let explanation = result[i].description;
      let created_at = result[i].created_at;
      let updated_at = result[i].updated_at;
      let sqlData = [sid, githubid, name, githuburl, explanation, created_at, updated_at];

      console.log(sqlData);

      let sql = `INSERT INTO Personal_Data (id, githubid, name, githuburl, explanation, pjdate1, pjdate2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`;
      db.query(sql, sqlData);
    }
```

and then it works fine like this

: Console

```
[ 'FUuBdByBV',
  'sangumee',
  'Blueinno2',
  'https://github.com/sangumee/Blueinno2',
  'This repository uses BlueInno 2 and shares the source code written.',
  '2018-06-11T04:08:17Z',
  '2018-12-04T07:48:08Z' ]
[ 'HiRsc7IjNc',
  'sangumee',
  'CSS-Grid',
  'https://github.com/sangumee/CSS-Grid',
  'CSS Grid Study',
  '2018-07-13T07:49:57Z',
  '2018-07-19T05:17:14Z' ]
```